# _args and _kwargs arguments for python

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


class Countries(object):
        def __init__(self,*_args,**_kwargs):
                self.name = 'japan'
                self.continent = 'asia'
                self.capital = 'tokyo'
                print _args
                print _kwargs

        def display(self):
                print self.name, self.continent,self.capital




iraq = Countries('iraq','bagdad','asia')

iraq.display()

india = Countries('india','delhi','asia')

india.display()
```

I have written a self teaching example above.I know that irrespective of the parameters I am always assigning

```
'japan' , 'asia' , 'tokyo'
```

to the member variables of the class.I wrote the above in an attempt to understand

```
   *_args and **_kwargs
```

The output of the above program is as below

```
('iraq', 'bagdad', 'asia')
{}
japan asia tokyo
('india', 'delhi', 'asia')
{}
japan asia tokyo
```

where _args is `('iraq', 'bagdad', 'asia')`

and __kwargs is `{}`

why is a null string being printed for `_kwargs` and all arguments printed as a list for `_args`

Comment: `{}` isn't a "null string" by any reasonable meaning of the term…

Comment: Also, given the way you've called this, what did you _expect_ to see in `_args` and `_kwargs`?

Comment: @abarnert - good question.I thought it was similar to argc and argv[].Obviously _kwargs is used for keyword arguments for e.g capital='bagdad'. What I don't get however is the basic reason for such an approach? Is it to support variable number of arguments for constructors?

Comment: Makes sense. But if you think about it, the only reason you need `argc` at all is that C arrays don't know their own length. (That's why Python has a `sys.argv` but no `sys.argc`.) Anyway, the basic reason for `*args` and `**kwargs` is to support both variable arguments and keyword arguments, and for _all_ functions, not just constructors. Almost any prototype you could describe to a person, you can easily implement in Python. (There are a few minor limitations in 2.x, but they're fixed in 3.x.)

Comment: And as for why you _want_ keyword arguments: Look at something like [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) in the stdlib. With keywords, I can do `check_output(args, universal_newlines=True)`. Without them, I'd have to do `check_output(args, None, None, False, True)`—which means I'd have to look up what all the other arguments are, and their default values, just to say I don't care. Plus, it's a whole lot less readable, unless I add a comment for each argument to show which parameter it matches (and which are non-default).

Comment: @abarnert - excellent explanation.I am a C/C++ programmer just getting started on Python.This is the kind of explanation that I need at this stage :) thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you aren't passing in any keyword arguments.  If you did `Countries('Iraq', capital='Bagdad')`, then it would print something for kwargs.

Comment: I would also suggest looking at this answer to understand the mechanics behind *args and **kwargs:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3394898/288570